# nobr in HTML (HTML5)

Tags: html

I would like to single letters were not on the end of a paragraph i site. I know it 2 ways:

A)

```
<p>... <nobr>a może</nobr> tak ...</p>
```

B)

```
<p>... a&nbsp;może tak ...</p>
```

Which one is better and should be used today? Or maybe another?
It would be nice if it was as easy to work with.

Comment: They work equally well, so the choice is a matter of opinion and personal preferences. This may be affected by opinions regarding specifications (`nobr` is not defined in any spec, yet universally supported). In more complicated cases (e.g. words contain hyphens) there may be technical reasons to favor one or the other.

Answer (score 0):

Mozilla states, that `<nobr>` is deprecated and also never was standard HTML. So it isn't recommended to use it at all:
[<nobr> on developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr)

But Mozilla doesn't recommend using `&nbsp;` as a substitute, but to use the CSS style `white-space` instead:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

My understanding is, that you should use `&nbsp;` only when single word pairs shouldn't get divided. For example, if you have abbreviations of units behind an amount, like 5 ml:

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet 5&nbsp;ml</p>
```

This also is more like a piece of content-based information since it describes, that those two words belong together and should not get separated in order to maintain readability and a good understanding.

Whereas `<nobr>` has been designed to make whole paragraphs do not add line breaks.

And this already explains, why `<nobr>` is not a standard HTML tag, since HTML should only contain content-related information, and everything about style/design should go into the stylesheet.